# mvnDebug mode is not opening the debug mode

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I have a maven project which I m trying to execute using mvnDebug clean install command but it is getting stuck at below point and nothing happens after this:

```
mvnDebug clean install
Preparing to execute Maven in debug mode
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000 (Stucked here and nothing happens after this)
```

Debug configuration in Eclipse is shown in image:[image: Eclipse Config]

Also if I am trying to debug from java class itself by right clicking and selecting Debug as > Debug configurations (same configuration as shown in image) > debug then it is working fine just for the first time and opening the debug perspective. But If i perform the same actions I get "Launching remote encountered a problem, failed to connect to remote VM.Connection refused".

Comment: What would you like to debug? Your application/Test etc. or Maven/Maven Plugins?

Comment: i have my java code within the plugin as well as I have code under src/test as well so I would like to put a breakup anywhere within my framework and debug it

Comment: So you are developing a Maven plugin?

Comment: yes i have a multi module maven project with already developed maven plugin which executes a piece of code and then after plugin execution my tests run

Comment: You wrote to put the break point into the framework which is not part of the plugin? Do you have tests for your framework? You need to start Eclipse remote debugging after starting the mvnDebug process... cause it's waiting for a connection...

Comment: breakpoint I am applying into the code which is a part of plugin only. Start eclipse remote debugging how? I mean for now my steps are 1. Setting a breakpoint in one of the lines of code 2. Then from console using mvn clean install command.